# How can I compare a BigDecimal with ActiveRecord decimal field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bigdecimal

Assume a schema like this:

```
create_table "bills", :force => true do |t|
  t.decimal  "cost", :precision => 10, :scale => 5
end
```

I want to write a function that writes a new bill to the DB iff it is unique. The following does not work:

```
def load_bill_unless_exists(candidate)
  incumbents = Bill.scoped.where(:cost => candidate.cost)
  candidate.save unless incumbents.exists?
end
```

because the incumbent bills and the candidate bills have different limits in their BigDecimal representation, so the `:cost => candidate.cost` test fails. That is, it's comparing:

```
candidate: #<Bill id: nil, cost: #<BigDecimal:105e39850,'0.1670576666 6666666E4',27(27)>>
```

with

```
incumbent: #<ServiceBill id: 198449, cost: #<BigDecimal:105e35840,'0.167057667E4',18(18)>>
```

Notice the candidate's BigDecimal represents the cost with more digits than the incumbent.

So the question is simple: What's the right way to perform this comparison? I contemplated `:cost => BigDecimal.new(candidate.cost.to_s, 18)`, but that doesn't feel right -- for example, where does that number 18 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `BigDecimal#round`:

```
def load_bill_unless_exists(candidate)
  incumbents = Bill.scoped.where(:cost => candidate.cost.round(5))
  candidate.save unless incumbents.exists?
end
```

From the docs:

> Round to the nearest 1 (by default), returning the result as a BigDecimal. If n is specified and positive, the fractional part of the result has no more than that many digits.

Given that you've specified a precision of 5 in your schema, that's what you should be rounding to when doing comparisons.

Comment: Ah! That seems exactly right.  I'll test it out -- you'll get the checkmark if it works.

Comment: Yep - that worked perfectly.  I embellished your solution with `COST_SCALE = Bill.columns.find {|r| r.name == 'cost'}.scale` and then (later) `incumbents = Bill.scoped.where(:cost => candidate.cost.round(COST_SCALE)` to avoid sticking magic numbers like '5' in my code.

Comment: I too had issue where I need to compare a money value like `16.94 == 16.939999999999999` for validation before saving. I then round off it to `2` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If casting like you were contemplating works, you probably have to go with that.  The query you're using is just building a "WHERE cost = number" and if the database isn't able to compare properly with the number as passed, you need to pass it differently.  It looks like it's the database stopping you and not anything within Rails necessarily.

If you just don't like casting within your query, you could always do it in the model:

```
def cost_with_incumbent_precision
  BigDecimal.new(cost.to_s, 18)
end
```

Comment: Well, I clearly don't understand the significant digits argument to BigDecimal.new().  For example, BigDecimal.new('1670.5766666666666') == BigDecimal.new('1670.5766666666666', 3) => true.  So, no, casting as I was contemplating doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try round or truncate?  cost.round(18) or cost.truncate(18)?  Your main problem is the string that gets generated in the SQL statement isn't seen by the database as being the same thing as what it has in the incumbent table.