# How to properly compare database-persisted BigDecimal to another value using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, bigdecimal

The objective is to use ActiveRecord methods like `#where` and `#first_or_create` to properly compare a database-persisted BigDecimal value against a Float or String value.

create_things migration:

```
t.decimal :position, :precision => 10, :scale => 4
```

relevant code:

```
position = "0.309624"
thing = Thing.where(:position => position).first_or_create
thing2 = Thing.where(:position => position).first_or_initialize
```

the issue:

I'm expecting `Thing.count` to equal 1 and `thing2.persisted?` to be `true`, meaning Active Record was able to properly compare `position` with `thing.position` to find the first record and assign it to `thing2`.

debugging:

```
thing.position #> #<BigDecimal:7ffbdabe42a8,'0.309624E0',9(18)>
thing.position == position #> false
```

it's possible to do a valid comparison by converting both variables...

```
thing.position.to_s == position#> true
thing.position.to_f == position.to_f #> true
```

... but this requires a conversion of the database-persisted value. Is there a way to make this happen using `#where` and/or `#first_or_create`?

see also [How can I compare a BigDecimal with ActiveRecord decimal field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297230/how-can-i-compare-a-bigdecimal-with-activerecord-decimal-field)

edit: this question is different from the related question in that the accepted solution to the related question advocates rounding a float, which applied to this example would call for an assignment of `position = "0.309624".to_f.round(4)`, which still produces an invalid comparison.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you linked to? You're comparing a decimal with scale of 6 to a DB column with a scale of 4, so you need to round just as the answer in the linked question states

Comment: its close but the accepted solution to that question advocates using `#round`, which applied to this example would call for an assignment of `position = "0.309624".to_f.round(4)`, which produces the same invalid comparison noted in this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compare a BigDecimal with ActiveRecord decimal field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297230/how-can-i-compare-a-bigdecimal-with-activerecord-decimal-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, which is to convert the position to BigDecimal before comparison:

```
position = BigDecimal.new("0.309624", 4) # where 4 is the decimal scale.
```

It seems so simple now...

edit: the BigDecimal also needs to be rounded before storing in the database and when comparing against database value:

```
position = BigDecimal.new("0.309624", 4).round(4)
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the linked answer states? `BigDecimal.new` is redundant: `"0.309624".to_d.round(4) == BigDecimal.new("0.309624", 4).round(4)`